# openssl_pkcs7_sign(), цифровая подпись недействительна

Tags: php, openssl, mime

Взял в Comodo бесплатный сертификат для S/MIME подписи емейлов. Сохранил его в P12 и затем конвертировал в PEM. Получил ключ и сертификаты.

```
Key: openssl pkcs12 -in "comodo.p12" -out "key.pem" -nocerts
Cert: openssl pkcs12 -in "comodo.p12" -out "cert.pem" -clcerts -nokeys
CAs: openssl pkcs12 -in "comodo.p12" -out "chain.pem" -cacerts
```

Посылаю тестовый емейл.

```
$data = <<<EOD

You have my authorization to spend $10,000 on dinner expenses.

The CEO
EOD;

$fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

if(openssl_pkcs7_sign("msg.txt", "signed.txt",
    "file://".realpath("cert.pem"),
    array("file://".realpath("key.pem"), "password"),
    array("From" => "Me <me@domain.com>"),
    PKCS7_DETACHED,
    "chain.pem"
)) {

$data = file_get_contents("signed.txt");
$parts = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);

mail("test@domain.com", "Signed message.", $parts[1], $parts[0]);

} else {
    echo openssl_error_string();
}
```

Открываю андроидный GMAIL и вижу в заголовке "Цифровая подпись недействительна". Если нажать на ссылку "Информация об отправителе", то показывает "Удостоверяющий центр:    COMODO RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email CA" и предлагает скачать сертификаты.

Взял триальный сертификат в GlobalSign для проверки, тоже самое! Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Где может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо убедиться, что на стороне клиента не используется алгоритм SHA1. Google не доверяет этому алгоритму, нужно выбрать SHA256 или любой другой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]